# Created admin's users doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I have a big problem with creating users from the admin panel;

Users are created correctly, but they do not work on the main page ..

Then I create an admin type user and I will log in with the main page and I get an error: 'those credentials do not match our records'

which is the error?

admin/userController

```
public function store(SaveUserRequest $request)
{    
     $data = [
        'name'          => $request->get('name'),
        'last_name'     => $request->get('last_name'),
        'email'         => $request->get('email'),
        'user'          => $request->get('user'),
        'password'      => $request->get('password'),
        'type'          => $request->get('type'),
        'active'        => $request->has('active') ? 1 : 0,
        'address'       => $request->get('address')
     ];

     $user = User::create($data);
     $message = $user ? 'Usuario agregado correctamente!' : 'El usuario NO pudo agregarse!';
     return redirect()->route('admin.user.index')->with('message', $message);   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you do not hash your password, when saving the user (you can verify this by looking in the users table in your database and check if you can see the clear text in the passwords column for your users).

To correct this, just replace

```
'password' => $request->get('password'),
```

with

```
'password' => bcrypt($request->get('password')),
```

in your `$data` array.

Hope that helps!